# Books read in 80s, English mythology with modern twist, male writer

Tags: story-identification

A male writer, books were aimed at early teens, paranormal, he wrote about English mythology giving it a modern twist. I remember one about a boy who accidentally broke a fairy compact, releasing an evil spirit from a tree.

Comment: This seems fairly vague- can you give any more information?

Comment: Yes, can you remember any of the names, specific incidents, when you read it, any key phrases, whether it was one book or a series, style of writing, illustrations, book cover, etc.

Comment: Was the writer American or British, or English? Or were the books you remember published in America or Britain?